# Applying @PreAuthorize to a method contained in a Spring Roo-generated ITD (*.aj)

Tags: spring, spring-security, aspectj, spring-roo, spring-aop

I would like to apply the Spring Security **`@PreAuthorize`** annotation to a **service method defined in the following Spring Roo ITD** (without performing a push in refactor of the method):

```
privileged aspect CurriculumServiceImpl_Roo_Service {

  declare @type: CurriculumServiceImpl: @Service;

  declare @type: CurriculumServiceImpl: @Transactional;


  public Curriculum CurriculumServiceImpl.updateCurriculum(Curriculum curriculum) {
    return curriculumRepository.save(curriculum);
  }
```

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: The recommended way to customize code is push in the code then customize, why don't you want to push in the updateCurriculum() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this using Spring Roo: [**See detailed comment here.**](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3230?focusedCommentId=92820&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-92820)

To **quote the comment**:

> If you want try and use the PermissionEvaluator, follow these steps
>   (preferably on a test project).
>
> 1. Run the Roo command "permissionEvaluator --package {the package to which you want to add the PermissionEvaluator} " (security must be
>      installed first)
> 2. Spring Roo will create three files: ApplicationPermissionEvaluator, ApplicationPermissionEvaluator_Roo_PermissionEvaluator,
>      applicationContext-security-permissionEvaluator.xml.
> 3. Add userPermissionEvalutor=true to the @RooService annotation of the service you want to secure.
> 4. Spring Roo will append additional criteria to @PreAuthorize e.g. "OR hasPermission(#myDomanObject,
>      'MyService:deleteMyDomainObjectIsAllowed')"
> 5. Add/Update the method hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetObject, Object permission)) in
>      ApplicationPermissionEvaluator

By the way performing a push in refactor is not a solution for my application. It is always better to **go the Roo way** and rely on Roo features.